# RangeSlider for specifying range of heights (in feet and inches) using NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, type-conversion, rangeslider, numberformatter

I am using a RangeSlider which is a UIControl type:

https://github.com/WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider

It has a property called numberFormatter. I want to give the slider a minimum and maximum value, say, in inches (minValue = 48 inches, maxValue = 96 inches)....and it should show the heights on the slider in this kind of format:

48 (inches) will be formatted as string "4'0''" i.e. 4 feet 0 inches

49 inches -> "4'1''"

...
74 inches -> "6'2''"

etc.

OR feet -> feet and inches:

6.08333 -> "6'1''" etc.

how can i specify these formats for an instance of RangeSlider?

Here is documentation for NumberFormatter:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter

I created a subclass of NumberFormatter. How do i make it so that the RangeSlider instance calls this override function each time it needs to display the formatted height on the labels of the two thumbs?

```
class HeightFormatter : NumberFormatter{
    override func string(from number: NSNumber) -> String? {
        let feet = number.int32Value/12
        let inches = number.int32Value % 12

        let height = "\(feet)"+"'"+"\(inches)"+"\""
        return height
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to implement your own custom `NumberFormatter` subclass. The standard formatter can't handle conversions to/from feet/inches.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they belong to the site and its users. If you would like to delete your question, click the delete button under your post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about...what do you mean by "vandalize your posts"?...i deleted a response to rmaddy because i was still trying to figure things out...i als edited my original post to avoid confusing people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just assign an instance of your new number formatter to the `numberFormatter` property of the slider:

```
slider.numberFormatter = HeightFormatter()
```

Comment: brilliant ....i think this worked, Palle !!! thanks...i didn't have to do anything else